# PHP update nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql

So this the code in the edit.php document

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include_once("db.php");

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header("Location: login.php");  
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        header("Location: index.php");  
        return;
    }

    if(!isset($_GET['pid'])){
        header("Location: index.php");  
    } else {
        echo "This seems to work";
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        echo $pid;
    }
        if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
            $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
            $content = strip_tags($_POST['content']);

            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $title);
            $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content);

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET title='$title', content='$content' WHERE id='$pid'";

            if($title == "" || $content == ""){
            echo "Please complete your post!";
            return;

        }
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog - Post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="edit.php" method="edit" enctype="mutlipart/form-data">
        <input placeholder="Title" name="title" type="text" autofocus size="48"><br  /><br />
        <textarea placeholder="Content" name="content" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea><br />
        <input name="edit" type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in db.php

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname")
?>
```

I know I am doing something very wrong with the update thing because it doesn't want to update. But I don't know how to fix it. Help please?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Comment: Instead of header() write "echo $sql;" then check Your build query. It might be also related to You table structure, so try to copy-paste that query into phpMyAdmin and check for errors.

Comment: turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` DO a check on `mysqli_query` if it was successful. If not return the error from `$db->connect_error`

Answer (score 0):

```
method="post" //change to post. Default is get

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="mutlipart/form-data">
```

we use `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`, because everything is happening on the same page.

Using prepared statements,

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET title=?, content=? WHERE id=?";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('ssi', $title, $content, $pid);   
if($statement->execute()){
       //all good
} else {
   echo $db->error;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said use PDO.

If you want to keep using the code you've already got. Change the form tags to:

```
  <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="mutlipart/form-data">
```